# I am unable to install my app in Tizen emulator due to "Invalid certificate chain with certificate in signature error"

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

I have packaged my web based Tizen app in .wgt package. Previously, I used to run it in Tizen emulator without any problem. But, since last few days, I am unable to run it in emulator. Whenever I try to install the app in Tizen emulator, I get "Invalid certificate chain with certificate in signature error" error. My app is already available for sale in Tizen store but I am unable to figure out that what is wrong now.

Since my app is already available in Tizen store, I do have author and distributor certificate.

I follow following steps to generate the .wgt package

```
$ tizen security-profiles add -n AppProfile \
    -a /path/to/tizen/certs/author.p12 -p <cert-password> \
    -d /path/to/tizen/certs/distributor.p12 -dp <cert-password> 

   
$ tizen cli-config "profiles.path=$TIZEN_SDK/tizen-studio-data/profile/profiles.xml"
$ tizen security-profiles list -n AppProfile
$ tizen package -t wgt -s AppProfile
```

^ it produces a .wgt package

I setup my emulator by following steps:

```
$ cd $TIZEN_STUDIO/package-manager
$ ./package-manager-cli.bin install Emulator
$ ./package-manager-cli.bin install WEARABLE-4.0-Emulator


$ cd $TIZEN_STUDIO/tools/emulator/bin
$ ./em-cli list-package


$ ./em-cli create -n test-vm -p wearable-4.0-circle-x86
$ ./em-cli launch -n test-vm
```

This creates and launch the emulator. Then I drag and drop the .wgt package in the emulator to install the app. Previously it used to install without any problem but now it throws the mentioned error. Screenshot attached.[image]

Comment: Is your distributor certificate valid? Isn't it expired?

Comment: I tried by creating a new distributor certificate too but the issue persists.